# Node-expat wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: c++, node.js, elf

I'm having to build my node application on a build machine then move the application over to a target machine as I'm unable to compile C on my target machine as required by some of my dependancies.

I'm having a compilation error with node-expat which is spitting the above ELF class error. I've tried rebuilding my node application on both 32 and 64 bit versions of linux though seems to through the issue when I port it over to my target machines (which is supposedly a 64 bit machine).

I'm getting these errors on build:

```
node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/lumos/runner/node_modules/logbook/node_modules/simple-xmpp/node_modules/node-xmpp/node_modules/node-expat/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/expat/deps/libexpat/lib/xmlparse.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/expat/deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.o
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:471:1: warning: missing initializer
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:471:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘latin1_encoding_ns.isName2’)
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:484:1: warning: missing initializer
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:484:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘latin1_encoding.isName2’)
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:504:1: warning: missing initializer
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:504:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘ascii_encoding_ns.isName2’)
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:517:1: warning: missing initializer
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:517:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘ascii_encoding.isName2’)
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:730:1: warning: missing initializer
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:730:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘little2_encoding_ns.isName2’)
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:749:1: warning: missing initializer
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:749:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘little2_encoding.isName2’)
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:762:1: warning: missing initializer
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:762:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘internal_little2_encoding_ns.isName2’)
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:775:1: warning: missing initializer
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:775:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘internal_little2_encoding.isName2’)
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:871:1: warning: missing initializer
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:871:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘big2_encoding_ns.isName2’)
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:890:1: warning: missing initializer
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:890:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘big2_encoding.isName2’)
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/expat/deps/libexpat/lib/xmlrole.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/libexpat/libexpat.a
  COPY Release/libexpat.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node_expat/node-expat.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/node_expat.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/node_expat.node: Finished
  COPY Release/node_expat.node
make: Leaving directory `/root/lumos/runner/node_modules/logbook/node_modules/simple-xmpp/node_modules/node-xmpp/node_modules/node-expat/build'
```

Though it runs fine on the machine I'm building on. When I try to run it on my target machine I'm getting the following:

```
module.js:356
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^
Error: /root/lumos/runner/node_modules/logbook/node_modules/simple-xmpp/node_modules/node-xmpp/node_modules/node-expat/build/Release/node_expat.node: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/lumos/runner/node_modules/logbook/node_modules/simple-xmpp/node_modules/node-xmpp/node_modules/node-expat/lib/node-expat.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
bash-4.1#
```

Is ELFCLASS64 telling me that the application is trying to call 64bit libs or 32bit libs? Can do I force node-expat to compile using the correct libs though node-gyp/npm?

Answer (score 3):

> Is `ELFCLASS64` telling me that the application is trying to call 64bit libs or 32bit libs?

It is telling you that a 32-bit process attempted to `dlopen` a 64-bit library.

It's not clear from your description how you invoke the `node`, but the binary you are invoking on the target machine is a 32-bit binary, which can't load 64-bit shared libraries.

You need to either invoke 64-bit binary instead, or build your libraries in 32-bit mode.